# For each loop through sheets with Selection.AutoFill

Tags: excel, vba

This doesn't compile.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test3()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Sheets
        sht.Range("C1").FormulaArray = "=A1&B1"
        sht.Range("C1").Select
        sht.Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Next sht
End Sub
```

The error

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

is on:

```
sht.Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I also tried

```
Option Explicit
Sub test3()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Sheets
        sht.Range("C1").FormulaArray = "=A1&B1"
        sht.Range("C1").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Next sht
End Sub
```

This can work depending on the sheet I have active. For example if I have sheets(1) active it works on Sheets(1) but then on Sheets(2) I get an error:

> Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed

Comment: I forgot to mention... if I step through the code... and I manually select each tab as the code moves from one sheet to the next... it works fantastically on all sheets....

Comment: You can’t select a sheet’s cell without selecting the sheet first. So above the line `sht.Range("C1").Select` you’d put `sht.Select`

Comment: That said, it’s recommended that you rewrite your function to not use `.Select` at all

Comment: Thank you!! Since everybody and their brother says "it’s recommended that you rewrite your function to not use .Select at all" I have basically no experience using ".Select" which explains why I didn't know/remember that I needed to select the sheet. That said, what is a good alternative to using select in this situation?

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/2727437)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for the activesheet (Using sheets array is referencing the active workbook).

```
For Each sht In Sheets
    sht.Range("C1").FormulaArray = "=A1&B1"
    sht.Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=sht.Range("C1:C3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Next sht
```

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated!!